# Use 9 patch or icons of all sizes

Tags: android

What is the appropriate way:

1. Make a 9 patch image of each icon & put in the `drawable`
   folder.
2. Make icons for `mpdi, hdpi, xhdpi & xxhdpi` size separately.

Comment: The best site I found to generate all icon sizes is : http://makeappicon.com/ . Its just drag and drop and it will generate all icon sizes.

Answer (score 1):

If your images are more than just borders and contain more than just a few lines, use the second approach.